# ANCS and BLE113

Tags: ios, bluegiga, ancs

I am using the ANCS service to get notifications on BLE113. It works fine except I can only get 20 bytes of data as that is the MTU restriction. Since iOS sends data larger than 20 bytes, I miss anything more than 20 bytes. BLE113 attclient_attribute_value event only reads 20 bytes.

How can I read rest of the data?
I tried read long but it gives me a read not permitted error.

Has anyone encountered this problem and/or found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Nordic 8001 chip which has also 20 bytes MTU. From ANCS documentation:

> If the response is larger than the negotiated GATT Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU), it is split into multiple fragments by the NP. The NC must recompose the response by splicing each fragment. The response is complete when the complete tuples for each requested attribute has been received.

So if the message is larger than 20 bytes you should received more 20 bytes fragments.